# AmazonS3Client Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to instantiate an `AmazonS3Client` object using directly passed `AccessKey`, `Secret` and `Region` (I've also tried using a `BasicAWSCredentials` object with the same result). We already have a credential store mechanism and I do not want to try and have a separate external store just for this process.

I've also tried using a `BasicAWSCredentials` object with the same result.  I've also had it register the profile locally as well hoping that would allow it to work.

```
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKey, Secret, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

The result is this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\.aws\credentials'

Comment: Possible instance of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666615/instantiating-amazons3client-in-c-sharp-using-the-access-key-secret-key-and-reg?